# How do I change Outlook's "Archive" location for IMAP accounts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook 2016 has an "Archive" button shortcut to backspace. On my IMAP email account, I have per-year Archive directories (eg archive_17, archive_18, archive_19). For the new year, I'd like to change the Archive folder to archive_19.  I've done this previously to go from archive_16 to archive_17 etc, but now I cannot find where I set the Archive folder any more.

**How do I change the Archive location for *IMAP* accounts?**

Microsoft's page on Archive in Outlook for Windows only discusses Office 365 accounts, for which:

> The Archive folder is one of Outlook's default system folders and cannot be renamed, moved, or deleted.

But this is *definitely untrue* for IMAP accounts, because my Archive button sends mail to `Inbox/Archive_18` right now. I want to change it *from* that to `Inbox/Archive` .  Clearly I set the archive location before. Where have they moved that setting?

Answer (score 1):

Found it after a lot of searching. You have to select the IMAP inbox in the Folders pane at the left of the screen, then go to the File tab, then "Mailbox Settings", then you can set archive folder.

[image: Mailbox Settings in the Outlook "File" tab]

It is not in Account Settings or Folder Properties or User Profile, and this setting is not stored in the registry. Also you need to have the IMAP inbox selected, and not any other folder.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't reproduce your steps to resolve it. Please will you add more screenshots to show the process?